# PHP error that only happens in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I'm getting a PHP error that only seems to happen in IE...

The error I'm getting is:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in absentAddGen.php on line 6
```

Line 5, 6, 7, and 8 are:

```
5:$studentname = $_POST['nameQ'];
6:list($lastname, $firstname) = explode(',',$studentname);
7:$firstname = trim($firstname);
8:$lastname = trim($lastname);
```

This error doesn't happen in Chrome or Firefox... any idea on what could be causing it?

Having server-side code fail on a different browser doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Looks like $studentname doesn't have a comma in it in the IE example:-) How are you passing that to the server?

Comment: what is the expected value of $_POST['nameQ'] and what is the actual value of $_POST['nameQ']?

Comment: It's not an error, it's a notice. Most probably `$_POST['nameQ']` does not contain `name,surname`, but only `name`.

Comment: $_POST['nameQ'] is undefined in IE. Defined in other browsers.

Comment: Then your problem is very probably in your HTML or Javascript code

Comment: Yep, it had to do with my jQuery selector. Still a bit of a weird error, but it ended up not being PHP related. Thanks anyways guys!

Answer (score 3):

`$studentname` doesn't contain a `,`:

```
list($lastname, $firstname) = explode(',',$studentname);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$tmp = explode(',', $studentname);
$lastname = $tmp[0];
$firstname = $tmp[1];
```

If there is no comma in `$studentname`, `explode()` returns an array with only one element. When trying to get the second element (offset 1), PHP shows a notice.

The `Undefined offset: 1` error means that you tried to read the offset `1` of an array that doesn't have an element at offset `1`.

Make sure you are sending the correct value in `$_POST['nameQ']`

Comment: There will always be a "," in $studentname

Comment: Apparently not. Try echoing `$studentname` to verify.

Comment: @adamzwakk This answer is correct, and the fact that you are only getting this in IE suggests that you have a JS validator that doesn't work/do what you expect in IE but works everywhere else. Check your client side scripting relating to the `nameQ` field on your form.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search on "php error undefined offset" brought me to this link:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3793272.htm

and I have to wonder if something similar is happening with your list where it is running off the end of the list instead of the end of an array. I suspect your comma is not be used to separate the names somehow.